# Typescript не понимает функция ли свойство

Tags: javascript, typescript

Всем привет, у меня есть такая структура

```
interface IValidation {
    required: {
        value: boolean,
        message: string
    },
    pattern: {
        value: string | ((value: string) => boolean),
        message: string
    }
}
```

И я пытаюсь

```
Будем считать что validations[key] это {
key: pattern: {value: (data) => return true}
}

if(validations[key]?.pattern &&
 Object.prototype.toString.call(validations[key]?.pattern?.value) === "[object Function]") {
      return validations[key].pattern?.value(value);
 }
```

Почему typescript не понимает что это функция?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал так же

```
if(validations[key]?.pattern && validations[key]?.pattern?.value instanceof Function) {
    return validations[key].pattern?.value(value);
}

if(validations[key]?.pattern && typeof validations[key]?.pattern?.value !== "string") {
     return validations[key].pattern?.value(value);
}
```

Comment: с `instanceof` тоже не работало?

Comment: _`value.toString() !== "[object Function]"`_  - очень странная проверка

Comment: @Grundy, с instanceof Тоже не работает

Comment: сделай [mcve] на https://www.typescriptlang.org/play - с instanceof у меня заработал пример, возможно у тебя что-то другое проверяется

Comment: @Grundy, не очень понял как воспроизвести на ts площадке, это реакт компонент https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-7pzw0w?file=/src/useValidate.tsx

Comment: проблема в `validations[key]`, сохрани значение в переменную и потом ее в условии используй.